# IME Resize Options for Horizontal Orientation

Tags: android, ime

I've created a custom IME for Android tablets and I'm having trouble resizing when the screen is in horizontal orientation. Whenever an `EditText` is clicked while the screen is horizontal, the IME takes over the entire screen with the standard `EditText` and `Button` combo with my custom IME at the bottom of the screen. However, I'd like for the IME to simply pop up without that and type directly into the field that was originally clicked, as it does in horizontal orientation. I've looked at the SoftKeyboard example, which accomplishes this (at least on honeycomb) and can't find exactly where they are setting that effect.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I've tried searching but couldn't find this exact question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having this issue, you can prevent your IME from entering fullscreen mode by overriding the onEvaluateFullscreenMode() method, which is what determines whether or not your IME will display in full screen.

Now I'm having different issues but that's for a different thread!